# Cannot find constraint by id

Tags: swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I have a button with `Center X Alignment Constraint` and this constraint's `identifier` is `"constBtnSound"`.

I'm trying to get this `constraint` with the following code **but cannot find it**.

```
for const in btnSound.constraints {
  if const.identifier == "constBtnSound" {
        ...
    }
}
```

Properties of the constraint:

[image]

All constraints of the button:

[image]

Comment: I've never use a constraint identifier before. If I need access to a constraint through code I'll control-drag the constraint into the owning object's source code to create an outlet to the constraint. That works well.

Comment: Is the constaint actually attached to the superview rather than to the "Btn Sound" view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what [the `UIView.addConstraint` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622523-addconstraint) says:

> The constraint must involve only views that are within scope of the receiving view. Specifically, any views involved must be either the receiving view itself, or a subview of the receiving view.

Since `button.superview` is not `button` and is not a subview of `button`, the constraint **cannot** be held by `button`.

Since `button` is a subview of `button.superview`, the constraint **can** be held by `button.superview` (or any ancestor of `button.superview`).

However, instead of searching for the constraint by id, you could create an outlet for it:

```
@IBOutlet var buttonXCenterConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Connect the outlet to the constraint in your storyboard.